# Embedding of finite groups into general linear group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

It's clear that for any field $\mathbb{F}$ any finite group $G$ can be embedded into $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ for some $n$.

My question is about one modification of this result.
Let's fix positive integer $N$. Is it true that for any finite group $G$ there exist a field $\mathbb{F}$ such that $G$ is embeddable into $GL_N(\mathbb{F})$?

**UPD:** For $N=1$ it's false. Let's consider $N>1$.

Comment: This can hardly be true for $N=1$..

Comment: Sure, for $N>1$ it is false if $G$ isn't cyclic.

Comment: @leb85 is this a well-known result? Is there an example of a finite group that can't be embedded in $GL_2(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: @Omnom: (he probably meant "for $N=1$")

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Of course, I meant $N=1$, sorry.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom for example, the smallest degree of an irreducible representation of $S_n$ is $n-1$ when $n\geq 7$

Comment: @AlexanderGruber That's true in characteristic $0$. But there is a representation of $S_n$ of degree $n-2$ in characteristic $p$ when $p|n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime that is not the characteristic of the field. Consider elementary abelian groups $C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$.

Now $x^p = 1$ has no repeated roots, so any of these elementary abelian groups in $GL_n$ will be simultaenously diagonalizable. But for fixed $n$, there are only finitely many diagonal matrices $A \in GL_n$ satisfying $A^p = 1$. Thus if the number of factors is large enough, then $C_p \times \cdots C_p$ does not embed into $GL_n$

Answer (score 4):

The symmetric group $S_n$ has no faithful representation of degree less than $n-2$ over any field, so the answer to the question is no for every $N$.

Comment: is this a well-known statement?

Comment: It's what you might call well-known in characteristic 0 (or coprime characteristic). I am finding it hard to pin down the original reference for the modular case! But there's a huge amount of literature on the representations of $S_n$!